# Репликация файлов с между различными платформами с распределением по конечным директориям

Tags: репликация, dfs

Добрый день, уважаемые эксперты. 
Существует сеть региональных ДЦ в которых скапливаются файлы для репликации(перемещения) в центральный ДЦ. С центрального ДЦ все файлы раскидываются по нескольким серверам распознавания. Работает это с использованием DFS + рукописный репликатор на C#. На текущий момент вся инфраструктура построена на Windows, однако, мы по-тихонечку переезжаем на unix системы.
В связи с этим возникла необходимость смены текущей системы репликации. Т.к. переезд будет не моментальным и не все сервера переедут на unix необходимо некое кросс-платформенное решение. **Необходимым требованием является распределение всего файлопотока центрального ДЦ по нескольким узлам с балансировкой нагрузки.** 
Как программист, я не сильно разбираюсь в данной области, и мне хочется сесть и написать репликатор с учетом всех нюансов проекта.
Но если подобные решения уже есть(или же связка технологий, которая решает данную задачу), зачем изобретать велосипед?

Как бы Вы решили данную задачу? Возможно, посоветуете решения которые (почти) подходят, желательно OpenSource, но и коммерческие продукты готов рассмотреть.

Comment: так Win DFS умеет работать с *nix. Если сейчас все работает как  нужно и производительности хватает, то просто меняете в DFS ссылки на конечные хранилища. Ну и стоит попробовать оптимизировать настройки репликации самой DFS. Хотя при большой территориальной удаленности качество каналов связи и расстояния будут влиять больше чем настройка DFS и репликации.

Comment: Может глупость скажу, но SyncThing или в крайнем случае BittorentSync не рассматривали?

Comment: Да, решений по репликации файлов много с помощью разных подходов(p2p, rsync, qfs и т.д.), но ни в каких из них я не нашел необходимого требования: балансировка по конечным директориям(pdf в одну директорию, doc в другую, или распределение вне зависимости от расширения по директориям в равномерном по объему(или количеству файлов) порядке). Ключевое требование именно балансировка.

Comment: похоже что в вашем случае придется таки писать свое, так как подобного функционала я тоже не видел. Все обычно заканчивается на репликации изменений, чтобы содержимое было везде одинаковым.